# To simplify $f_a(x)= \int_{-a}^{+a} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}\;dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Let $x\leq0$, then $$  f_a(x)= \int_{-a}^{+a} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}\;dt$$

$$  f'(x)= -\int_{-a}^{+a} \frac{1}{t^2-a^2} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt$$

$$  f'(x)= -\int_{-a}^{+a}  \frac{t^2-(t^2-a^2)}{a^2(t^2-a^2)} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt$$

$$  f'(x)= -\int_{-a}^{+a} \frac{t^2}{a^2(t^2-a^2)} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt + \int_{-a}^{+a}  \frac{1}{a^2} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt$$

$$  f'(x)= -\int_{-a}^{+a} \frac{t^2}{a^2(t^2-a^2)} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt +  \frac{f(x)}{a^2} $$

$$  f''(x)= \int_{-a}^{+a} \frac{t^2}{a^2(t^2-a^2)^2} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt +  \frac{f'(x)}{a^2} $$

$$  f''(x)= \frac{1 }{2xa^2}\int_{-a}^{+a} t\frac{2xt }{(t^2-a^2)^2} e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt +  \frac{f'(x)}{a^2} $$

$$  f''(x)= \frac{1 }{2xa^2}(te^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}|{_{-a}^{+a}})-\frac{1 }{2xa^2}\int_{-a}^{+a}  e^ {-\frac{x}{t^2-a^2}}dt +  \frac{f'(x)}{a^2} $$

$$  f''(x)= -\frac{f(x) }{2xa^2}  +  \frac{f'(x)}{a^2} $$

$$  a^2f''(x) -  f'(x)+\frac{f(x) }{2x}=0   $$

wolframalpha gave me [that long result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2f%27%27%28x%29%20-%20%20f%27%28x%29%2b%5Cfrac%7Bf%28x%29%20%7D%7B2x%7D=0%20) :

[image]

Can you please help me  with some technics to simplify $f_a(x)$ ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It seems $f_a(x)$ is infinite when $a\ne0$ and $x\gt0$.

Comment: Yes you are right typo should be x<=0 . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$
f_a(x) = \frac{\operatorname{e} ^{x/(2a^2)} x}{a} \biggl(\mathrm K_0 \biggl(\frac{-x}{2 a^{2}}\biggr) - \mathrm K_1 \biggl(\frac{-x}{2 a^{2}}\biggr)\biggr),\qquad x<0
$$
in terms of Bessel functions.

**added**

It should work like this:  The function $f$ listed on the right-hand-side satisfies the differential equation.  And the "initial conditions" 
$$
f(0) = 2a,\qquad
f'(x) \sim \frac{-1}{a}\,\log\left(-x\right)\qquad\text{as } x \uparrow 0
$$
match $f_a$, therefore this one is equal to $f_a$.

Comment: Could you please give more detail how you got that result? Thanks